# Is it possible to open JFileChooser over Canvas?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, awt

Is there any alternative way to open a `JFileChooser` in which a `JFrame` only contains a `Canvas`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. 
Taking a look at the documentation of `Canvas`, seem the only component one can add is a `PopMenu`

Comment: thanks for your response @Joseph bro
i just got my answer
i just add jfilechooser in the my frame's contentpane :)

Comment: Right, `Canvas` is not a `Container`.

Answer (score 1):

- not possible without dirty hacks, I'd suggest to use [JPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) instead of `Canvas`,
- lightweight `Swing JComponents` are behind `AWT Components`,
- for painting to Swing JComponents to use `paintComponent` instead of `paint`
- I'd suggest don't mixing `AWT Components (Canvas)` with `Swing JComponents (JFrame or JFileChooser)`